# Do need to atlas textures when using draw call minimizer?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just downloaded [draw call minimizer](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2859) from the asset store, and I can't figure out one thing. In my project I'm using basically one material as color palette - my models are low poly so I just map UVs on the correct color. Because of this I don't know if there is any reason to use atlas textures feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using [Vertex Painting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_painting) to reduce amount of texture data then you don't need to make atlas. And in your case, as you have only one texture as color palette you don't need to atlas your texture because usually atlas is required for more than one textures.